# Putting json.loads response inside of dataclasses

Tags: python, json

I created a couple of dataclasses (similar to Go's structs) and I want to put my response/data inside of the dataclass. I haven't been able to find wether or not the `json` package supports this out of the box.

Dataclasses

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class TakerPays:
    currency: str
    issuer: str
    value: str


@dataclass
class Offers:
    account: str
    book_directory: str
    book_node: str
    flags: int
    ledger_entry_type: str
    owner_node: str
    previous_tx_id: str
    previous_tx_lgr_seq: int
    sequence: int
    taker_gets: str
    taker_pays: TakerPays
    index: str
    owner_funds: str
    quality: str


@dataclass
class Warnings:
    id: int
    message: str


@dataclass
class Result:
    ledger_hash: str
    ledger_index: int
    offers: List[Offers]
    validated: bool
    warnings: List[Warnings]


@dataclass
class Response:
    id: int
    result: Result
    status: str
    type: str
```

Preview of the json that needs to be put into the `Response` dataclass

```json
{
  "id": 4,
  "result": {
    "ledger_hash": "5848C7DB5024EC3B532AC2F93BA8086A3D6281D3C0746BFE62E7E3CF4853F663",
    "ledger_index": 68379996,
    "offers": [
      {
        "Account": "rPbMHxs7vy5t6e19tYfqG7XJ6Fog8EPZLk",
        "BookDirectory": "DFA3B6DDAB58C7E8E5D944E736DA4B7046C30E4F460FD9DE4E1D157637A1048F",
        "BookNode": "0",
        "Flags": 0,
        "LedgerEntryType": "Offer",
        "OwnerNode": "0",
        "PreviousTxnID": "72B8928E31DF89223C7ADE0030685289BAD772C72DF23DDFFB92FF7B48BAC622",
        "PreviousTxnLgrSeq": 68379985,
        "Sequence": 386826,
        "TakerGets": "789784836",
        "TakerPays": {
          "currency": "USD",
          "issuer": "rvYAfWj5gh67oV6fW32ZzP3Aw4Eubs59B",
          "value": "646.5472316"
        },
        "index": "82F565EDEF8661D7D9C92A75E2F0F5DBF2BAAFAE96A5A5A768AD76B933016031",
        "owner_funds": "4587408572",
        "quality": "0.0000008186371808232591"
      }
    ],
    "validated": true,
    "warnings": [
      {
        "id": 1004,
        "message": "This is a reporting server.  The default behavior of a reporting server is to only return validated data. If you are looking for not yet validated data, include \"ledger_index : current\" in your request, which will cause this server to forward the request to a p2p node. If the forward is successful the response will include \"forwarded\" : \"true\""
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "success",
  "type": "response"
}
```

I've not been able to find support to put the json into the dataclass similar to Go's `json.Unmarshal` and I'm curious to the best way to do this

Comment: You can pass a dictionary as keyword arguments to create a class instance using the `**` syntax, but you would have to work your way up from the inner levels of the JSON structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the builtin modules in Python such as `json` don't support de-serializing JSON into a *nested dataclass* model as in this case.

If you're on board with using third-party libraries, a solid option is to leverage the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library for this task, as shown below; one advantage that it offers - which really helps in this particular example - is auto *key casing* transforms, such as from "camelCase" and "TitleCase".

Note that if you prefer not to subclass from any Mixin class, you can opt to use the helper functions `fromdict` and `asdict` to convert data from/to Python `dict` objects instead.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class TakerPays:
    currency: str
    issuer: str
    value: str


@dataclass
class Offers:
    account: str
    book_directory: str
    book_node: str
    flags: int
    ledger_entry_type: str
    owner_node: str
    previous_txn_id: str
    previous_txn_lgr_seq: int
    sequence: int
    taker_gets: str
    taker_pays: TakerPays
    index: str
    owner_funds: str
    quality: str


@dataclass
class Warnings:
    id: int
    message: str


@dataclass
class Result:
    ledger_hash: str
    ledger_index: int
    offers: List[Offers]
    validated: bool
    warnings: List[Warnings]


@dataclass
class Response(JSONWizard):
    id: int
    result: Result
    status: str
    type: str


def main():
    string = r"""
    {
      "id": 4,
      "result": {
        "ledger_hash": "5848C7DB5024EC3B532AC2F93BA8086A3D6281D3C0746BFE62E7E3CF4853F663",
        "ledger_index": 68379996,
        "offers": [
          {
            "Account": "rPbMHxs7vy5t6e19tYfqG7XJ6Fog8EPZLk",
            "BookDirectory": "DFA3B6DDAB58C7E8E5D944E736DA4B7046C30E4F460FD9DE4E1D157637A1048F",
            "BookNode": "0",
            "Flags": 0,
            "LedgerEntryType": "Offer",
            "OwnerNode": "0",
            "PreviousTxnID": "72B8928E31DF89223C7ADE0030685289BAD772C72DF23DDFFB92FF7B48BAC622",
            "PreviousTxnLgrSeq": 68379985,
            "Sequence": 386826,
            "TakerGets": "789784836",
            "TakerPays": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "issuer": "rvYAfWj5gh67oV6fW32ZzP3Aw4Eubs59B",
              "value": "646.5472316"
            },
            "index": "82F565EDEF8661D7D9C92A75E2F0F5DBF2BAAFAE96A5A5A768AD76B933016031",
            "owner_funds": "4587408572",
            "quality": "0.0000008186371808232591"
          }
        ],
        "validated": true,
        "warnings": [
          {
            "id": 1004,
            "message": "This is a reporting server.  The default behavior of a reporting server is to only return validated data. If you are looking for not yet validated data, include \"ledger_index : current\" in your request, which will cause this server to forward the request to a p2p node. If the forward is successful the response will include \"forwarded\" : \"true\""
          }
        ]
      },
      "status": "success",
      "type": "response"
    }
    """

    r = Response.from_json(string)
    print(repr(r))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Response(id=4, result=Result(ledger_hash='5848C7DB5024EC3B532AC2F93BA8086A3D6281D3C0746BFE62E7E3CF4853F663', ledger_index=68379996, offers=[Offers(account='rPbMHxs7vy5t6e19tYfqG7XJ6Fog8EPZLk', book_directory='DFA3B6DDAB58C7E8E5D944E736DA4B7046C30E4F460FD9DE4E1D157637A1048F', book_node='0', flags=0, ledger_entry_type='Offer', owner_node='0', previous_txn_id='72B8928E31DF89223C7ADE0030685289BAD772C72DF23DDFFB92FF7B48BAC622', previous_txn_lgr_seq=68379985, sequence=386826, taker_gets='789784836', taker_pays=TakerPays(currency='USD', issuer='rvYAfWj5gh67oV6fW32ZzP3Aw4Eubs59B', value='646.5472316'), index='82F565EDEF8661D7D9C92A75E2F0F5DBF2BAAFAE96A5A5A768AD76B933016031', owner_funds='4587408572', quality='0.0000008186371808232591')], validated=True, warnings=[Warnings(id=1004, message='This is a reporting server.  The default behavior of a reporting server is to only return validated data. If you are looking for not yet validated data, include "ledger_index : current" in your request, which will cause this server to forward the request to a p2p node. If the forward is successful the response will include "forwarded" : "true"')]), status='success', type='response')
```

---

*NB*: I noted that two fields in the `Offers` dataclass have slightly different names than the fields in the JSON object. For example, the field `previous_tx_id` is associated with the key `PreviousTxnID` in the JSON object.

Assuming this was intentional, you could easily work around this by defining a field *alias* mapping, as shown below:

```py
from dataclass_wizard import json_key
# Note: In Python 3.9+ you can import this from `typing` instead
from typing_extensions import Annotated  

@dataclass
class Offers:
    ...
    previous_tx_id: Annotated[str, json_key('PreviousTxnID')]
    previous_tx_lgr_seq: Annotated[int, json_key('PreviousTxnLgrSeq')]
    ...
```